# security issue in using google login api

Tags: html, google-signin

Whether there is a security issue in using google login api . Since when we inspect the site the client id is visible to all. Any one else can use the client id which they get from the page inspect.

Comment: I use html5 and javascript

Comment: Please provide more detail, what you mean by  `the client id is visible to all`